# Is there room for improvement in this sentence? Complex sentence

Tags: word-choice, grammar, errors, complex-sentences

The sentence is the following:

> Along the years, I've developed a keen computational thinking which in
>   addition to my sharp aesthetic judgment made me a really valuable
>   player for any cross-functional agile team.

Is there room for improvement in this sentence? Is there any grammatical error? Is the sentence to complex?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Yes, yes, and no.  I think this question may fall outside the scope of this site as it appears to be a request for proofreading, but I will defer to more experienced users.

Comment: Oh, I am really sorry if that's the case. I thought it was appropriate for this site. I will delete the question if it falls out of the scope of this website. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: No need to delete, as I may be wrong.  I would wait for an answer, were I you.

Comment: Your use of commas is poor.  "Over the years" is more idiomatic.  The correct spelling is "too complex", not "to complex".  And you're gushing too much about yourself.

Comment: For some reason, 'computational thinking' just seems to be odd, not quite right in that sentence.

Comment: 'Lateral thinking' fits better than computational thinking.

Comment: Over the years [corrected the idiom], I have [don't use contraction] developed a keen ability [better than "a keen thinking"] for logical [versus computational] thinking which, [comma use] in addition to my sharp aesthetic judgment, [comma use] has made [tense] me a [don't use the word "really"; too simplistic] valuable player in/to [either preposition, but not "for"] any cross-functional agile team.

Comment: @Nonnal thank you very much for your answer. I found it excellent! I would love to pick it as the correct answer for my question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're a designer in tech?  I've interviewed many.  Your page will be scanned, not read.  You must clearly indicate your unique strengths, and the value of those strengths to the interviewer.

Uniqueness:

> I translate design ideas into terms developers can understand.

Value:

> This allows me to take a leadership role in cross-functional teams.

Be prepared to give examples of these assertions.

Comment: Excellent contribution. Thank you very much for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: @NMO Thanks ... you get to vote one of these up. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> Along the years, I've developed a keen computational thinking which in
>   addition to my sharp aesthetic judgment made me a really valuable
>   player for any cross-functional agile team.

This sentence is saying very little with too much. Less is more when you're trying to look like you're good at something:

> My logical and strategic thinking have made me a valuable team member.

Says about the same thing, could be better:

> I am valued for my logical and strategic thinking in team settings.

And then if you want something to just translate what you wrote more clearly:

> Over the years, I've developed computational skills and sharp aesthetic  judgment, which make me a valuable member for any cross-functional agile team.

Tip - words like "really" and "very" in sentences like these weaken the point you try to make. "Really very good at math" sounds like you don't know what you're talking about. "Good at math" does.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I found your answer really useful.